# I want to import two classes from the same file one of them depend on the other

Tags: python, import, scope, dependencies, python-import

I have a file with two classes as follows:

```
# file1.py

class ApiConfig():
  def __init__(self, ip: str = ""):
    self.ip = ip
    ...

class Base_api():
  method_name = None
  params = None
  ip = ""
  def __new__(config: ApiConfig, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ip = config.ip
    self.__init__(config, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
  ...
```

now I want to import class ApiConfig and Base_api in file2 :

```
# file2.py

import file1
# from file1 import ApiConfig,Base_api 

class Login(Base_api):
  method_name = "Login"
  def __init__(self, config: ApiConfig, user: str = "usr", password: str = "pwd"):
    self.params = {"user": user,"password": password}
    ...
  ...

class Browse(Base_api):
  method_name = "Browse"
  ...
```

when I call the file2 classes in main.py

```
# main.py

from Subfolder.file2 import login

login()
```

I get the following error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Base_api' from 'file1'

when all the classes are in the same file it works but I need to split the program for organisational purposes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a [mre], we should be able to reproduce your problem by running exactly the same code you share. Visit the [help] center and read [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: You can try 
" from file_name import * "

Comment: it's good practice to use consistent capitalisation, i.e. `BaseApi` for the class name instead of `base_api`

Answer (score 0):

In file2.py, when using `import file1`, you have to put `file1.` before everything you import from there.

```py
import file1

api_config = file1.ApiConfig()
```

Or, as you already wrote, but commented out:

```py
from file1 import ApiConfig, base_api
```

PS:
In file1 you're missing some `self`

Answer (score 0):

ok so I discovered that the problem was that the files were is a subfolder, so the import line in file2 had to be:

```
 from Subfolder.file1 import ApiConfig,Base_api
```